# How to save document with images (not local path)?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word document create with some picts. When I send this file to other people, they don't see the pictures. It seems that the pictures are not embedded in the document and that there is only a local path.

How can I ask Word to embed the picture in the word file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to embed an image:-

1. Go to `Insert` Menu

   - `Picture` (from `Illustrations` Section)
   - Browse your image
   - Insert the Image
2. Go to `Insert` Menu

   - `Object` (from `Text` Section)
   - Click on `Create from file`
   - Browse your image (Note that don't check the box **`"Link to file"`**)
   - Click `OK`

After doing this, you might have whether it will work or not.

Yes, you can test.

### Follow below steps to confirm:

1. Copy the file
2. Paste the file in some different folder
3. Go to the image location
4. Change the image file name
5. Come back to the document location (either new location OR old location OR try both)
6. Open the word file
7. You will see images appearing